# Reconnecting form responses to current sheet after file move to Team Drive

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms, google-sheets-query, google-workspace-for-business, google-shared-drive

I have searched for an answer for the "current" Google Forms problem I am having.  It seems the answers here for this issue are outdated as Google keeps changing their technology about as fast as I can change underwear.

I had a drive set up for my organization's files under my personal account and shared the files with them.  We have a form there that we use and it has about 500 responses.

My organization switched to G-Suite and I have been migrating our files over to the new team drive.  I recently copied the form and the sheet over to the new Team Drive and the connection between the form and sheet was lost.  I tried reconnecting them, but the form wants to create a new sheet within the existing spreadsheet and then shows no responses.

I thought "fine, I'll just copy the responses over to the newly created sheet from the older sheet and let it pick up from where it left off."  Nope, this didn't work either.  It does not see the previous responses.

I tried following the linking instructions on the G-Suite education site for form responses, but that also didn't work.

Is there any way I can fix this issue with the current system?  We want the previous responses to show up in the graphs, etc. that you can view for form responses.

I will humbly take the downvotes if this really has been answered recently for the current version of their web apps, and I apologize if it is already answered.

Comment: from your story, it looks like you feed your charts directly from acquired responses... did you consider an option to use a simple query on a hidden sheet and merge the old dataset with the new one and feed your charts from there?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but no, I did not know that was an option.  Do you have a link I view to figure that out?

Answer (score -1):

- let's say that responses from Form come in **Sheet1**
- create **Sheet2** sheet in your spreadsheet
- copy over those previous 500 responses to **Sheet2**
- on row 501 of **Sheet2** paste this **`QUERY`** formula:

  ```
  =QUERY({Sheet1!A2:Z}, "select * where Col1 is not null", 0)
  ```
- or create **Sheet3** and paste this **`QUERY`** into **A1** cell:

  ```
  =QUERY({Sheet1!A1:Z1;Sheet2!A1:Z;Sheet1!A2:Z}, "select * where Col1 is not null", 1)
  ```
- now when the old and the new dataset are merged under one sheet edit your graphs/charts to reflect this change and feed them from **Sheet2** (or Sheet3)
- extra sheets can be hidden by right-clicking them and selecting **Hide sheet** option